# Subset a dataframe by another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes: `df1`

```
   IDs          Value1      Value2        Value     Value4
   AB              1          1             1       5
   BC              2          2             2       3
   BG              1          1             4       1
   RF              2          2             2       7
```

and `df2`

```
   Index          0                1             2         3
   1              True           False          True       True
   2              False          False          True       False
   3              False          False          True       False
   4              False          False          False      False
```

with the same number of columns and rows.
`df1` contains `integer` values, while `df2` contains `Boolean` values.
What I need is to subset `df1` in the following manner: get only the columns that in `df2` have at least on `True` value.

Expected output:

```
   IDs          Value1         Value3     Value4
   AB              1              1       5
   BC              2              2       3
   BG              1              4       1
   RF              2              2       7
```

How can I do that without iterrations and lists, but using pandas functions?

Expected ouput:
Thank you.

Comment: Provide reproducible df and code of what you have tried till bow

Comment: You should provide [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for quicker and better responses.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that this kind of questions suits stackoverflow, but here is a way:

```
d1 = df1.values # extract values as numpy array, should be int
d2 = df2.values # extract values as numpy array, should be bool
d2_any = np.any(d2,axis=0) # sets true if any of the values along the axis is true. see official man.
selected = d1[:,d2_any] # select the correct columns
```